# Broadcast Problem Algorithm In Parallel Computing In Mesh, Complete Tree and Hypercube Structures

Tags: algorithms, parallel-computing

Can anyone please help me design an algorithm to solve the broadcast problem in parallel for the structures mentioned?

Comment: This sounds like a classical problem whose solution can be found in the literature.

Comment: What do you mean by "help you"? It seems, actually, that you want us to do the whole thing.